# Firestore - Adding a new field sets it as "map"

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to add a new field inside my document.
When I'm setting it, it sets the field as string (what I need)
But when I'm trying to add something new `(update)`, it sets it as `map`
[image]

Code:

```
await firestore().collection(groupID).doc('images').collection(licenseNumber).doc('images')
.get()
.then((docSnapshot) => {
    if (docSnapshot.exists) {
        getImages();
        firestore().collection(groupID).doc('images').collection(licenseNumber).doc('images')
            .update({
                // [length]: reference.child(response.assets[0].fileName).fullPath,
                [response.assets[0].fileName.toString()]: reference.child(response.assets[0].fileName).fullPath,
            })
            .then(() => {

                setIsLoading(false);
            })
    } else {
        getImages();
        firestore().collection(groupID).doc('images').collection(licenseNumber).doc('images')
            .set({
                // [length]: reference.child(response.assets[0].fileName).fullPath,
                [response.assets[0].fileName.toString()]: reference.child(response.assets[0].fileName).fullPath,
            })
            .then(() => {
                setIsLoading(false);
            })
    }
})
```

I don't know where is the problem. Maybe It's a stupid mistake or typo.

Answer (score 1):

That is expected behavior: when you have a `.` in the field name when **updating** a document, that dot is interpreted as indicated a path to a subfield. Such a mapping is not done when you call `set`.

So one option is to [call `set` with `merge: true`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document) to get the updating behavior in an operation that doesn't parse the `.`.

Alternatively you can construct a `FieldPath` object and pass that to `update`, in which case the `.` will (should?) be ignored there too.

Comment: Still not works, This is the Field name: `rn_image_picker_lib_temp_437b2b4a-347e-47a5-8490-cca3c89fad15.jpg`

Comment: Should I try `substring` the `.jpg`?

Comment: `substring` works nice!